# Transparent Background in render result but not in exported image

Tags: transparency

As the title said, when I view the rendered result it looks fine and it shows the transparent background : [image: what appears when i press render image]

Meanwhile, when i try to export it as a png it has a black background:  [image: RGB]

I have already tried to change the rgb thing with rgba but it exports as a white circle in a white background :
[image: RGBA]
I do not know what caused this since im fairly new to blender but here are the picture of the nodes in case i did something wrong : [image: nodes]
In case this is helpful, ill post the blender file here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/11VMxSpttG-cvmPSFXbfLteBW3Jh2ED0k/view?usp=sharing

EDIT: By exporting the image, I meant saving the image in my computer. When I save as RGBA it shows the sphere but no glare effect in what appears to be a white/transparent? background.
[image: RGBA]
While when I save as only RGB it saves as the sphere with the glare effect, but with a black background.
[image: RGB]

Comment: How are you viewing the saved PNG? Some viewing applications automatically show transparent pixels as black (i.e., essentially ignore the alpha channel)

Comment: it works fine for me, as NeverConvex says, it may be because of your image editor app?

Comment: Your *Alpha* is set to 0 in the *Composite* node, try setting it to 1, as per default.

Comment: Try to connect the Render Layers's Alpha with the Composite's Alpha socket.

Comment: same here, works fine. Maybe you can explain us what you mean with "when i try to export it"?

Answer (score 0):

In Compositing, connect *Alpha* socket of *Render Layers* node to *Alpha* socket of *Composite* node.